# Update Redux State & Then Get The Updated State In Same Instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, redux, react-redux

The Scenario:

I have a responsive `div` container (CSS - Width : 33%) with child images. Not wanting the user to scroll down, I want to find out the absolute dimensions of the `div`, so that I can calculate the number of images (which have fixed Width & Height) which can fit in. Then to render only the images which can fit on the screen.

I am using React & Redux for this app. Here is the logic I was thinking of, which does NOT work.

```
_ Smart Component (subscribed to the Store)
|___ `div` container (presentational component)
|______ images (presentational components)
```

I render the 'presentational' component, then in the `componentDidMount`, I dispatch a function which finds out the Width & Height of the `div` container & updates the Redux state with 'image capacity' value (how many images can be stored in the `div` container).

Immediately after the above function, while still in `componentDidMount`, I dispatch another function which should take the *UPDATED* values from the store (image capacity) & update the store with image data.

The idea being that when the store is updated, the smart component will re-render the presentational components (`div` & images) & thus a second round of re-rendering would occur to display the images.

Unfortunately, this is flawed. The props being passed to the presentational components are 'pre-update' store values (0) so when I run the dispatch the second function to update the store with images, the 'image capacity' value it has in its props is still zero (0).

I wonder what correct logic to implement here?

In case, the code makes more sense, here is the presentational component code:

```
const PreviewTemParent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount : function() {
        let elePreviewParent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this.refs.previewParent );
        previewTemParentAttr.width = elePreviewParent.clientWidth;
        previewTemParentAttr.height = elePreviewParent.clientHeight;
        this.props.findImgCapacity();
        this.temImgToShow( "body" );
    },
    temImgToShow : function( templateType ) {
        let pagination = this.props.previewTemState.get( "pagination" );
        let imgCapacity = this.props.previewTemState.get( "imgCapacity" );
        console.log( "%c     In `PreviewTemParent`, pag, imgCap & props are...", "color : gold", pagination, "; ", imgCapacity, "; ", this.props );
        this.props.temImgToShow( templateType, pagination, imgCapacity );
    },

    render : function() {
        return(
            <div
             className = "previewParent"
             ref = "previewParent">
                <div className = "previewContainer">
                    { this.props.previewTemState.get( "temImg" ).map( ( imgObj ) => {
                        <PreviewTemImgContainer data = { imgObj } />;
                    } ) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

### EDIT :

Upon @pierrepinard_2's request, Im posting a detailed code, hopefully explaining what I have tried.

I tried a few things, including adding a 'smart component' to the parent of `<PreviewTemParent>` & then getting the parent to calculate the dimensions. However, in that case the props are still not updated, understandably because the componentDidMount is run after `<PreviewTemParent>` has been mounted.

Here is the solution I tried as per suggestion from @pierrepinard_2 regarding using `componentWillReceiveProps`, which doesnt seem to be called.

**C_PreviewTemParent CONTAINER (SMART COMPONENT)**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { temImgToDisplayInContainer } from "../modcon/Actions.js";
import PreviewTemParent from "../component/temContainer/PreviewTemParent.jsx";

const mapStateToProps = ({ previewTemImgState }) => {
    return({
        previewTemState : previewTemImgState
    });
};
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return({
        temImgToDisplayInContainer : ( templateType, activePage ) => {
            dispatch( temImgToDisplayInContainer( templateType, activePage ) );
        }
    });
};

export const C_PreviewTemParent = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( PreviewTemParent );
```

**PreviewParent COMPONENT**

```
const PreviewTemParent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount : function() {
        this.props.temImgToDisplayInContainer( "body" );
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps : function( nextProps ) {
        console.log( "%c   componentWillReceiveProps is...", "color: green", nextProps );
    },
    render : function() {
        return(
            <div className = "previewParent">
                <div className = "previewContainer">
                    { this.props.previewTemState.get( "temImg" ).map( ( imgObj ) => {
                        <PreviewTemImgContainer data = { imgObj } />;
                    } ) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**ACTION CREATOR**
Please excuse the lengthy code :!

```
export const temImgToDisplayInContainer = ( templateType, activePage ) => {
    // temImgCapacity finds out the number of images that can 
    // fit in the container based on the container's dynamic Width & Height.
    // in order to make the func reusable, activePage is an optional parameter
    // hence the `if`
    let temImgCapacity;
    if( activePage ){
        temImgCapacity = findImgCapacityInPreviewTem( false );
    } else {
        temImgCapacity = findImgCapacityInPreviewTem( true );
    }
    // `previewTemImgData` is a store of static data of all the images.
    // during development, this is being used instead of ajax calls etc
    // `temImgData` stores the data only for the 'templates' we are interested in
    let temImgData = previewTemImgData.get( templateType );
    let counter = 1;
    // `noOfTemplate` is how many images we will render
    let noOfTemplate = temImgCapacity.get( "imgCapacity" );
    let currentPage = activePage || temImgCapacity.get( "activePage" );
    // `maxCounter` is for pagination, which is the last template to store
    let maxCounter = currentPage * noOfTemplate;
    let temStartFrom = (( currentPage * noOfTemplate ) - noOfTemplate );    // what template start number.
    // get the tempales we are only interested in
    let filteredTemImgData = temImgData.filter( ( templateObj ) => {
        if (( counter <= maxCounter ) && ( counter >= temStartFrom )) {
            counter++;
            return( templateObj );
        }
    } );
    // merging the data from above first line 'temImgCapacity' & the filtered
    // temImgData
    let payloadData = filteredTemImgData.merge(( temImgCapacity ));
    return({
        type : CURRENT_TEM_IMG,
        payload : payloadData
    });
};
```

**Finally, THE REDUCER**:

```
const previewTemImgState = ( state = initialPreviewTemState, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
    case( FIND_IMG_CAPACITY_IN_PREVIEW_TEM ) :
        return(
            state.set( "imgCapacity", action.payload.imgCapacity )
        );
    case( RENDER_TEM_IMG ) :
        console.log( action.payload );
        var newState = state.set( "temImg", action.payload.temImg );
        console.log( "%c   previewTemImgState is...", "color : red", state.get( "temImg" ), " ; ", newState.get( "temImg" ) );
        return(
            state.set( "temImg", action.payload )
        );
    default :
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: One way could be to move the call to `temImgToShow` to [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) method. You should first check whether imgCapacity prop has changed.

Comment: @HonzaHaering I have been thinking & trying to implement this, however, it  doesn't seem to make much difference. I think the problem is that the component instance doesn't know that the state has changed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to trigger only one action from componentDidMount() ? With following arguments: width and height (to calculate the image capacity), templateType, pagination. Then you would only get one UI update with desired state.

Comment: @pierrepinard_2 The issue is that, first I need to find the dimensions of the container (W & H) & then use those dimensions to update the state with the correct number of images. So, the sequence of events need to be:
--1-- render the image container component --2-- find the dimensions of the container --3-- update state with images to render --4-- render the image container along with its children components (images)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why you have to first update the state with images capacity, then update it once again with the images to show. Couldn't you perform these two state-updates through one cycle only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `this.props.previewTemState` in `temImgToShow()`, the state object reference is still the same as in the beginning of `componentDidMount()` execution, before `this.props.findImgCapacity()` was called.

One option would be to trigger only one synthetic action from `componentDidMount()`, with following arguments: width and height (to calculate the image capacity), templateType, pagination. Then you would only get one UI update with desired state.

If you really cannot trigger only one action to perform all the work, then you could fire the second action in `componentWillReceiveProps()` as Honza Haering suggested in comments:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    let elePreviewParent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode( this.refs.previewParent );
    previewTemParentAttr.width = elePreviewParent.clientWidth;
    previewTemParentAttr.height = elePreviewParent.clientHeight;
    this.props.findImgCapacity();
},

componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    let newImgCapacity = nextProps.previewTemState.get( "imgCapacity" );
    let oldImgCapacity = this.props.previewTemState.get( "imgCapacity" );
    if (newImgCapacity !== oldImgCapacity && newImgCapacity > 0) {
        let pagination = nextProps.previewTemState.get( "pagination" );
        nextProps.temImgToShow("body", pagination, newImgCapacity);
    }
},
```

Or, if you use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware, you could use async action creators with promises to properly chain actions. If you give us the code of your actions, I could show you how to do it.

Comment: many thanks pierrepinard_2. The point of separating the two was two folds, first that I dont want to be reading the DOM everytime the image container needs to be updated (which it will often), secondly to make it modular so I can use it elsewhere. Right now, Im trying to get the `componentWillReceiveProps` to work, not to much success. The problem is this:
When we update the Redux state in `componentDidMount`, I would have thought that the smart-container-component on top of image-container would call for a re-render of image-container. However, that doesnt seem to be happen... (tbc)

Comment: Merely doing a `console.log(nextProps)` within `componentWillReceiveProps` doesnt get invoked. It seems the the second re-render is not being called here.

Comment: Then I should see a bit more of your code (actions, reducers, containers, etc.). Would you have a link towards it?

Comment: I have updated the question, please read from below the 'EDIT'. Thank you for looking into this for me @pierrepinard_2

Comment: apologies, there was an error in my reducer & action.type. Now I am getting the console.log response! Im going to close this question and setup another one if I dont get the updated results from using the `componentWillReceiveProps`. Thanks again for going to such length to help me & the community :)